# Android ContentProvider Unique Queries

Tags: android, sql, android-contentprovider

I'm new to SQL so bear with me.

I have a database storing metadata for images.  When an image is viewed the intention is to pull the metadata from the database.  To query the images I have a URI column.  However I'm seeing crashes when users have an apostrophe in their filepath like such:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "s": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM meta WHERE (uri='file:///mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.dropbox.android/files/scratch/Sandra's%20pictures/Sandstone%20no%203%20ED01.tif')
```

The query is:

```
Cursor meta = mContext.getContentResolver().query(Meta.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, Meta.Data.URI + "='" + getUri() + "'", null, null);
```

It makes sense to me that apostrophe in "Sandra's" is terminating the uri string, but I'm not sure how to remedy this.  Is there a better way to query individual entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Gaëtan for pointing me in the right direction.  After digging into `DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString` I found that it's using `DatabaseUtils.appendEscapedSQLString` which is deprecated in most cases (including this one).

> This method is deprecated because we want to encourage everyone to use the "?" binding form.

The preferred way to insert the uri would be to use the selectionArgs parameter like such:

```
String[] selection = new String[]{ getUri().toString() };
Cursor meta = mContext.getContentResolver().query(Meta.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, Meta.Data.URI + "=?", selection, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should escape the string, try to use :

```
Cursor meta = mContext.getContentResolver().query(Meta.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, Meta.Data.URI + "=" + DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString(getUri()), null, null);
```